# Can Russian preposition "на" be used with any other country name besides Ukraine ("Украина")?

Tags: предлоги

Can Russian preposition "на" be used with any other country name besides Ukraine ("Украина")? Or is it like only in case with Ukraine it is correct to say "на" instead of "в" (that is "на Украине" instead of "в Украине")?

Answer (score 10):

На Руси.

It's a legal preposition for locations, but rarely used for countries, rather for some toponyms, e.g. на Волге, because it's also на реке - at river. Cuba and Taiwan are islands and  "on" island is to be на острове. Ukraine  only seems to be a rare case, but it isn't.. due the old meaning of country's name. It was derived from term  оукраина, that existed in medieval times. Basically it is something close to a fief. In Imperial time name of Ukraine was `Малороссия`, but it was generally called `украина` without specified name (a common term at that time, e.g. Ростовская украина), which slowly took over as a name of  province and was capitalized. By the way, the theory that name means окраина (province,  border, distant area) is considered methodologically incorrect. Regardless, both locations would require preposition на.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58062/discussion-on-answer-by-swift-can-russian-preposition--be-used-with-any-othe).

Answer (score 5):

The other ones that I know of the top of my head are Cuba and Taiwan.

Both of those are islands, so there could be a relationship there, since "на" can mean "on" such expressions might be implied to mean "on (island of) Cuba" but that's a speculation on my part

Comment: Also Jamaica; Samoa, Fiji, and other states on the Pacific islands. And surely _на Руси_.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think of "на Руси" it is an older expression, but certainly not invalid

Comment: @YellowSky - Is there any example of a country, which is not an island? And... is "Руси" a country?

Comment: Also Madagascar

Comment: @brilliant Русь was an old name referring to the lands that now would be Russia, Belarus and Ukraine and from which Russia takes its name, so it definitely was a country

Comment: @brilliant - _Rus'_ (Русь), later called [_Kievan Rus'_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kievan_Rus%27) (Киевская Русь) was a major medieval country.

Comment: Говоря о стране, никто не говорит "на Тайване".

Comment: @shabunc If you do a quick Google search you'll see that it is being used all the time. Ex.: На выборах на Тайване победу одержала Демократическая прогрессивная партия etc.

Comment: @Maxim, yes, you are right, my mistake, it is used indeed.

Comment: @Maxim - As far as I know, Russia doesn't recognize Taiwan as a separate country.

Comment: @YellowSky - Is there any example of a present-day country?

Comment: @brilliant - There seem to be no other present-day country beside Ukraine that's used with _на_, if not to count those situated on islands. Many Ukrainians don't like when _на_ is used referring to Ukraine, so in retaliation they often use _на_ with "Russia" (_на России_), but that's a kind of meme, not a norm.

Comment: shabunc монжно говорить на Тайване или в Народной Республике Тайваня ( хотя на самом деле нельзя, официально мы не признаем ее существование).

Comment: @Yellow Sky that's only if name of country at least supposedly matches name of island. Well, technically на is related to locative case there? На Украине, на Руси as locative case, and на Альбионе because it is an island etc.

Comment: @Swift - Note, that with some island-states you cannot use _на_ at all, for example you cannot say _*на Исландии_ or _*на Ирландии_, and there has never been a state called "Albion".

Comment: @Yellow Sky that's roman province's name, and poetic, sometimes mocking, name of Great Britain ( not mistaking it with United Kingdom). Well, yes, though  island is named same, to technically one could say so, while meaning island itself. It just uncommon and usually one would add  остров ). As often it happens a lot of such mores are based just on frequency of use and its sounding

Comment: @Swift - You're always using inaccurate terms, I'd like you improve your checking your sources. The name of the Roman province was [_Britannia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Britain), not "Albion".